# How to send invite events through emails using node js

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, mailgun

I need a solution for calendar invite to send mails with response Status through organizer mail id using node j s. I tried in different ways to get the email by using mail gun but I'm able create an event but unable to send and change the creator and also unable import the send invite mails using mail gun API. And I used move method to change organizer but unable to change it.
Here the picture shown below
[got calendar invite but need to send by using mail gun API to change organizer]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYtJF.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrQEX.png)

can anyone help me to sort out this issue. Thank you

Comment: Adding here that another alternative is google calendar api. See similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239387/node-js-send-meeting-calendar-invite-for-gmail) with different solutions/answers posted.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [node ics invite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics) send calender invites to user using mail attachments.

Comment: I used this functionality but getting an error as Invalid parameter type. from must be of type: string. I gave type : 'text/calendar; method=REQUEST',/ 'application/ics' . im able to create an event but unable to send the invite to the mails using mailgun